# panel is not working on dropdown click

Tags: asp.net, panel

This is mydesign part. i am showing panels on dropdwon click but its not working.
i have others tab too in tab container.

```
<ContentTemplate>
                    <h3 class="headr">Please Select a Category From Following</h3>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <asp:Image ID="culD" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="200px" class="dropbtn" ImageUrl="~/User/assets/Images/Explore/c_banner.jpg"></asp:Image>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="cult" Class="cultr" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cult_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="True">
                                <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="D">Dance</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="S">Singing</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="o">other</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown">

                        <asp:Image ID="sport" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="200px" class="dropbtn" ImageUrl="~/User/assets/Images/Explore/s_banner.jpg" />
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="sportsD" Class="cultr" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="sportsD_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="True">
                                <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="CR">Cricket</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="C">Chess</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="CRM">Carrom</asp:ListItem>

                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="dc">
                        <contenttemplate>
                            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="dan" class="npan" Width="900px" Height="500px">
                                <h3 style="text-align: center" class="panhed">Please Fill This Form TO Participate(Dance Registration)</h3>
                                <div id="snam" runat="server" class="nam">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name of participant:"></asp:Label>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="txtcls" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:Button ID="addm" class="addbtn" runat="server" autopostback="true" Text="Add member" OnClick="addm_Click" />

                                </div>
                                <div id="Div3" runat="server" class="nams">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" autopostback="true" Text="Name of 2nd participant:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" CssClass="txtscls" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Div29" runat="server" class="nams">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" Text="Age:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox22" CssClass="agtxt" placeholder="1st" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox24" CssClass="agstxt" placeholder="2nd" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>

                                <div id="Div2" runat="server" class="cate">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Select Category:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" Class="drpd" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="22">select</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Ss">Solo</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Dd">Duet</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Gg">Group</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divv" class="mobn" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Mobile No:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" CssClass="mobtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Div6" runat="server" class="eml">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="E-Mail:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" CssClass="emtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Div7" runat="server" class="yer">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Select Year:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList2" Class="drpds">
                                        <asp:ListItem>select</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>First</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Second</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Third</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>other</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Div8" runat="server" class="btndiv">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Class="Btncss" Text="Submit" />

                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </contenttemplate>
                     </asp:UpdatePanel>

                    <asp:Panel ID="singinp" runat="server" class="npan" Width="800px" Height="700px">
                        <h3 class="panhed">Please Fill This Form TO Participate(Singing Registration)</h3>
                        <div id="namep" runat="server" class="nam">
                            <asp:Label ID="name" runat="server" Text="Name of participant:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" CssClass="txtcls" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button6" class="addbtn" runat="server" autopostback="true" Text="Add member" OnClick="Button6_Click" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="namesp" runat="server" class="nams" autopostback="true">
                            <asp:Label ID="scndname" runat="server" autopostback="true" Text="Name of 2nd participant:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Txtnames" CssClass="txtscls" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div31" runat="server" class="nams">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text="Age:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox25" CssClass="agtxt" placeholder="1st" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox26" CssClass="agstxt" placeholder="2nd" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="cat" runat="server" class="cate">
                            <asp:Label ID="type" runat="server" Text="Select Category:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dcat" Class="drpd" Style="width: auto;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dcat_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem>select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Solo singing</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Duet singing</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Group singing</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>

                        <div id="clgn" runat="server" class="clgname">
                            <asp:Label ID="cname" runat="server" Text="Name of College:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="cnamet" CssClass="clgtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mob" runat="server" class="mobn">
                            <asp:Label ID="mobi" runat="server" Text="Mobile No:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Imob" CssClass="mobtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Email" runat="server" class="eml">
                            <asp:Label ID="emal" runat="server" Text="E-Mail:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="emao" CssClass="emtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="ydrp" runat="server" class="yer">
                            <asp:Label ID="yr" runat="server" Text="Select Year:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="yers" Class="drpds">
                                <asp:ListItem>select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>First</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Second</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Third</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>other</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div id="submit" runat="server" class="btndiv">
                            <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Class="Btncss" Text="Submit" />

                        </div>

                    </asp:Panel>

                    <asp:Panel ID="other" runat="server" Class="npan" Width="800px" Height="700px">

                        <h3 style="text-align: center" class="panhed">Please Fill This Form TO Participate(Other Event Registration)</h3>
                        <div id="Div1" runat="server" class="nam">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Textmode="MultiLine" Text="Name of participant/s:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" CssClass="txtc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div9" runat="server" class="cate">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Select Category:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList3" Class="drpd">
                                <asp:ListItem>select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Solo </asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Duet </asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Group</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div10" runat="server" class="nams">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Specify Event Name:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" CssClass="txtcs" runat="server" Placeholder="Ex-Drama/Fashion Show"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div11" runat="server" class="clgname">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Name of College:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" CssClass="clgtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div12" runat="server" class="mobn">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Mobile No:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" CssClass="mobtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div13" runat="server" class="eml">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="E-Mail:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" CssClass="emtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div14" runat="server" class="yer">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Select Year:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList4" Class="drpds">
                                <asp:ListItem>select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>First</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Second</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Third</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>other</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div15" runat="server" class="btndiv">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Class="Btncss" Text="Submit" />

                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>

                    <asp:Panel ID="chess" runat="server" Class="npan" Width="800px" Height="700px">

                        <h3 style="text-align: center" class="panhed">Please Fill This Form TO Participate(Chess Registration)</h3>
                        <div id="Div4" runat="server" class="nam">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Name of participant/s:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" CssClass="txtc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>

                        <div id="Div16" runat="server" class="nams">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="Age:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" CssClass="agtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div17" runat="server" class="clgname">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="Name of College:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" CssClass="clgtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div18" runat="server" class="mobn">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Mobile No:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" CssClass="mobtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div19" runat="server" class="eml">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="E-Mail:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" CssClass="emtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div20" runat="server" class="yer">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text="Select Year:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList6" Class="drpds">
                                <asp:ListItem>select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>First</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Second</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Third</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>other</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div21" runat="server" class="btndiv">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Class="Btncss" Text="Submit" />

                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="carup" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel ID="carrom" runat="server" Class="npan" Width="800px" Height="700px">

                                <h3 style="text-align: center" class="panhed">Please Fill This Form TO Participate(Carrom Registration)</h3>
                                <div id="Div5" runat="server" class="nam">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="Name of participant:"></asp:Label>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" CssClass="txtcls" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button5" class="addbtn" runat="server" Text="Add member" Autopostback="true" OnClick="Button5_Click" />

                                </div>
                                <div id="Div28" runat="server" class="nams">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label26" runat="server" autopostback="true" Text="Name of 2nd participant:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox20" CssClass="txtscls" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>

                                <div id="Div22" runat="server" class="nams">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" autopostback="true" Text="Age:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox16" CssClass="agtxt" placeholder="1st" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox21" CssClass="agstxt" placeholder="2nd" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Div23" runat="server" class="clgname">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server" Text="Name of College:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox17" CssClass="clgtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Div24" runat="server" class="mobn">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" Text="Mobile No:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox18" CssClass="mobtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Div25" runat="server" class="eml">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label24" runat="server" Text="E-Mail:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox19" CssClass="emtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Div26" runat="server" class="yer">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label25" runat="server" Text="Select Year:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList5" Class="drpds">
                                        <asp:ListItem>select</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>First</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Second</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Third</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>other</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Div27" runat="server" class="btndiv">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Class="Btncss" Text="Submit" />

                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>


                    <asp:Panel ID="cricket" runat="server" Class="npan" Width="800px" Height="700px">

                        <h3 style="text-align: center" class="panhed">Please Fill This Form TO Participate(Cricket Registration)</h3>
                        <div id="Div30" runat="server" class="nam">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Text="Name of participant/s:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox23" CssClass="txtcr" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div37" runat="server" class="clgname">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label34" runat="server" Text="Name of College:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox28" CssClass="clgtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div38" runat="server" class="mobn">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label35" runat="server" Text="Mobile No:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox29" CssClass="mobtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div39" runat="server" class="eml">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label36" runat="server" Text="E-Mail:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox30" CssClass="emtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div40" runat="server" class="yer">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label37" runat="server" Text="Select Year:"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList8" Class="drpds">
                                <asp:ListItem>select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>First</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Second</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Third</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>other</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div41" runat="server" class="btndiv">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Class="Btncss" Text="Submit" />

                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>

                   </asp:UpdatePanel>


                </ContentTemplate>
```

my codebehind

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class User_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=festopedia;Integrated Security=True");
    int FID;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showclg();
        dan.Visible = false;
        other.Visible = false;
        singinp.Visible = false;

        chess.Visible = false;
        cricket.Visible = false;
        carrom.Visible = false;

    }
    public void showclg()
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["FID"].ToString() == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Explore_Event.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            FID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["FID"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from FESTDETAILS where FID='" + FID + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            festexprepeater.DataSource = dt;
            festexprepeater.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    public void Showevent()
    {

    }



    protected void singb_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        singinp.Visible = true;
        dan.Visible = false;

    }
    protected void cult_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cult.SelectedValue =="D")
        {
            dan.Visible = true;
            singinp.Visible = false;
            other.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (cult.SelectedValue == "S")
        {
            singinp.Visible = true;
            dan.Visible = false;
            other.Visible = false;
        }


        else
        {
            other.Visible = true;
            singinp.Visible = false;
            dan.Visible = false;
            chess.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void sportsD_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sportsD.SelectedValue == "C")
        {
            dan.Visible = false;
            singinp.Visible = false;
            other.Visible = false;
            chess.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (sportsD.SelectedValue == "CRM")
        {
            carrom.Visible = true;
            dan.Visible = false;
            singinp.Visible = false;
            other.Visible = false;
            chess.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (sportsD.SelectedValue == "CR")
        {
            cricket.Visible = true;
            carrom.Visible = false;
            dan.Visible = false;
            singinp.Visible = false;
            other.Visible = false;
            chess.Visible = false;
        }
    }




    protected void addm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Div3.Visible = true;
        dan.Visible = true;
        TextBox24.Visible = true;


    }
    protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        carrom.Visible = true;
        TextBox21.Visible = true;
        Div28.Visible = true;
    }
    protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        carrom.Visible = true;
        TextBox26.Visible = true;
        namesp.Visible = true;
        singinp.Visible = true;
    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Dd")
        {
            addm.Visible = true;
        }
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Gg")
        {
            TextBox1.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
        }
    }
    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int charRows = 0;
        string tbCOntent;
        int chars = 0;
        tbCOntent = TextBox1.Text;
        TextBox1.Columns = 10;
        chars = tbCOntent.Length;
        charRows = chars / TextBox1.Columns;
        int remaining = chars - charRows * TextBox1.Columns;
        if (remaining == 0)
        {
            TextBox1.Rows = charRows;
            TextBox1.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1.Rows = charRows + 1;
            TextBox1.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
        }
    }
    protected void dcat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dcat.SelectedValue == "2")
        {
            Button6.Visible = true;
        }
    }


}
```

when i am clicking on image drop down panel is not getting visible.

Comment: plz remove code from the page and code behind that does not apply. there's way too much info. it looks like there are several similar things on the page. narrow it down to one. remove db stuff if it doesn't apply. i couldn't even find and image. tnx.

Comment: look at asp image tag.i.e image.as i am creating wesite so db stuff is for other part of that page that why it is in codebehind.

Comment: instead of an `asp:Image` control maybe you need an `asp:ImageButton` control which has OnClick and OnClientClick events.

Comment: i am showing dropdown on image hover